# Why is the second pattern not found or captured c#

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I have the following issue:

I am trying to parse an txt file output from a tool our developers use

Here is snippet of the file I am looking at

---

```
 DAT1                DAT(IL)
:NAME            R|OM_SW_1_ILP|AG
```

---

Now what I need to do is search for `DAT1` and then match up the text following `:NAME` with its corresponding `DAT`

Here is the regex pattern I am using it only seems to find the `DAT` not the name.

```
^(?<number>DAT[0-9]{1,3}).*(?<name>:NAME)?
```

I used expresso to test a ton of different combinations but none work

Please help

Comment: This looks like multi-line, what options do you feed to RegEx? And _what is_ the line structure?

Comment: So basically you want the string `R|OM_SW_1_ILP|AG`? Or this one *and * `DAT(IL)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`RegexOptions.Singleline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> **Singleline**
>
> Specifies single-line mode. Changes the meaning of the dot (.) so it matches every character (instead of every character except \n).

for matching a pattern across multiple lines.

Also you are looking for a **positive lookbehind** to find the text *after* `:NAME`.

---

**Example:**

```
void Main()
{
    var s = @"DAT1                DAT(IL)
              :NAME            R|OM_SW_1_ILP|AG";
    var p =  @"^(?<number>DAT[0-9]{1,3}).*(?<=:NAME\s+)(?<name>[^\s]*)";
    var m = Regex.Match(s, p, RegexOptions.Singleline);
    m.Groups["number"].Value.Dump();
    m.Groups["name"].Value.Dump();
}
```

**Result:**

> DAT1
>   R|OM_SW_1_ILP|AG

Comment: I don't know if you actually want `DAT1` or `DAT(IL)`, but it's easy adjust the pattern in my example to use a second lookbehind.

Answer (score 1):

Is `:NAME...` supposed to be on a new line? If so, you have to set the `RegexOptions.Multiline` option, or match the newline explicitly, *e.g.* `[\r\n]+`, because `.` doesn't match newlines.

Also, consider making `.*` non-greedy, *i.e.* `.*?`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `single line mode` to match your required data

```
(?<number>DAT[0-9]{1,3})(?<reqData>.*?)(?<name>:NAME)

//reqData group now contains your data
```

No need to use `^` here since you are going to match the text within a text file that can contain other data..